# DataGridTableStyle not working on .NET Compact framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing a Windows Form application on a Windows Mobile 6 device and I cannot get the datagrid to format correctly.  When I use the code below there are no columns displayed, it is either ignoring my code or it is incorrect but there are no errors generated.

```
DataGridTableStyle dgTableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
dgTableStyle.MappingName = tempDt.TableName;

DataGridTextBoxColumn dgSty_name = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
dgSty_name.HeaderText = "name";
dgSty_name.MappingName = "sty_name";
dgTableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(dgSty_name);

dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(dgTableStyle);
dataGrid1.DataSource = tempDt;
```

The datatable I am binding (tempDt) has about 6 columns in it, one of them is called **sty_name**.

Any help greatly appreciated as this is driving me mad!

thanks

Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it! **sty_name** needs to be in capitals!

Comment: In the famous words of Homer Simpson....  Dooohhhhh!!! When a datatable is queried, by default the column names are upper case.  I just ran into this myself... Thanks for your post and answer.

Comment: Can anyone point out, what I have to do, when my datasource is a List of Objects? I  referenced the Object name of my list, and the names of the public properties still it does NOTHING!